# How to manually import plugin dependency - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

I've been struggling with an old version of Eclipse 3.7 that is required by a (proprietary) plugin that I'm trying to install.

Got the following error when I try to import the plugin from an existing installation:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7B7DFO5F7RZHOeJ-SxQ1NJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7C79FULEdhO_pfuh6nYekfK0TyR2OK
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature,1.3.1.v201108102009-7F78FXRFBBoPbXRPcHfz-uy
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_core.feature,3.3.1.v20110729_1216-30FBc8s73553F5Ia2828
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature,3.3.1.v20110714_1706-7B77FGPAtJceyEUOhPIXVJNjBF39
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7E7EFMWAJun8_t84-MOI-iP7cRb5srz
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201107072200-7O7IFhREMiB5vNoYqf01XHTvUndyz-yx-9kUyXXL
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.3.1.v201108102009-7C7OFeKF7RZHQNI3R-OuRb
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201108102009-7H7EFZ3DxumTlaI6nheRdHo2p1KaDIL1Uz-S3PL
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml,1.3.4.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xerces,2.9.0.v201101211617
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.resolver,1.2.0.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.serializer,2.7.1.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.7.1.v20110830-1143
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.6.0.v20110905-0916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.7.0.v20110905-0902
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20110905-0916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.7.0.v20110905-0902
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.7.1.v20110829-1916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.7.0.v20110905-0916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.7.0.v20110520-1406
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.7.0.v20110905-0916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.7.0.v20110905-0916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.7.1.v20110830-1143
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem,2.0.500.v201104271400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.proxy,2.0.400.v201101101900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.1.100.v201103021400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.workbench,2.0.400.v201104251400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.controller,1.1.300.v200908252030
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.core,1.1.300.v201004141630
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks,1.1.500.v201104081500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.200.v201103170302
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.501.v201108231845
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.2.101.v201108110300
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb,1.1.503.v201108102200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca,1.1.500.v201108102200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.501.v201108231500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee,1.0.401.v201105122000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core,1.2.401.v201108302147
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui,1.1.601.v201108151912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.202.v20110419
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.core,1.2.0.v200908252030
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.100.v201101101900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.101.v201107140600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.environment,1.0.400.v200912181832
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.101.v201107192200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.100.v201105122000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.infopop,1.0.300.v201004280700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.101.v201108231700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui,1.0.101.v201108231700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.200.v201103170332
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.200.v201103311536
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets,1.2.100.v201103281740
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.ui,1.1.500.v200911190730
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.1.401.v201004280700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7B7DFO5F7RZHOeJ-SxQ1NJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7C79FULEdhO_pfuh6nYekfK0TyR2OK
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.500.v201104191926
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.600.v201103022054
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.doc.user,1.2.0.v200806052254
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.core,1.1.501.v201107252021
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui,1.0.600.v201103171359
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui.infopop,1.0.400.v201008112018
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtdeditor.doc.user,1.0.700.v201008112018
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.501.v201109080146
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui,1.0.601.v201108152113
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.infopop,1.0.200.v201004150328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache,1.0.400.v201004280700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.monitor.core,1.0.505.v20110419
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.monitor.ui,1.0.507.v20110817_1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.1.101.v201108151912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.core,2.0.100.v201103232243
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.rhino,1.0.100.v201103080228
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.rhino.debugger,1.0.200.v201103080228
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.rhino.ui,1.0.0.v201103232243
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.transport,1.0.0.v201008101442
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.ui,1.0.100.v201103232243
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc,1.0.400.v201011052052
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature,1.3.1.v201108102009-7F78FXRFBBoPbXRPcHfz-uy
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.manipulation,1.0.300.v201104272153
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.firefox,1.0.400.v201008112000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.ie,1.0.400.v201008112000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.101.v201108151912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core,1.0.401.v201108152113
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui,1.0.401.v201108152113
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.core,1.1.303.v20110816_1717
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.0.200.v20110518
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.1.306.v20110823_1704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user,1.1.400.v201104111553
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.infopop,1.1.100.v201005192130
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_core.feature,3.3.1.v20110729_1216-30FBc8s73553F5Ia2828
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature,3.3.1.v20110714_1706-7B77FGPAtJceyEUOhPIXVJNjBF39
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_userdoc.feature,3.3.0.v20110512-20DF7w312215222664
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.601.v201108151912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user,1.1.100.v201005192212
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.1.v201108191312
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.infopop,1.0.300.v201004150328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.standard.schemas,1.0.401.v201108151912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.302.v201107140600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.infopop,1.0.300.v200806041506
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui,1.2.204.v201004150700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web,1.1.500.v201104251400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web.ui,1.1.400.v201004141630
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.infopop,1.0.300.v200805140415
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7E7EFMWAJun8_t84-MOI-iP7cRb5srz
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201107072200-7O7IFhREMiB5vNoYqf01XHTvUndyz-yx-9kUyXXL
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_userdoc.feature,3.3.0.v201102200555-31Eo8s734B3E4H7799
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user,1.0.500.v201005192212
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.601.v201108302147
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.201.v201108151912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.infopop,1.0.400.v201004292007
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.3.1.v201108102009-7C7OFeKF7RZHQNI3R-OuRb
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201108102009-7H7EFZ3DxumTlaI6nheRdHo2p1KaDIL1Uz-S3PL
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_userdoc.feature,3.3.0.v201102071641-50FYwAkF7B77UBZFDBL
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user,1.0.700.v201005192212
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core,1.1.600.v201104070312
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui,1.2.404.v201105050216
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsdeditor.doc.user,1.0.800.v201005192212
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xsd,2.7.0.v20110905-0916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xsd.edit,2.6.0.v20110905-0916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jdom,1.0.0.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400
```

[Found the required dependencies](http://ftp.ntua.gr/eclipse/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.3.1/R-3.3.1-20110915193224/versioningReference_R-3.3.1-20110915193224.xml) on some FTPs, but I'm not sure how to convince Eclipse to import from there / manually. 
Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you install them from the official webtools site, links to all released versions are here:

- http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/

For Version R3.3.1 the URL is: https://archive.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.3/R3.3.1/R-3.3.1-20110915193224/ You can download the P2 repo for offline installation from [wtp-repo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.3/R3.3.1/R-3.3.1-20110915193224/wtp-repo-R-3.3.1-20110915193224.zip).

You can get an online P2 repo by adding "repository" to the end of the URL like this:
http://archive.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.3/R3.3.1/R-3.3.1-20110915193224/repository/

Comment: the above answer indeed fixed my original issue. Could you please provide the steps i should follow in order to find the repo for "osgi.bundle,javax.xml,1.3.4.v201005080400" for example (updated my question)

Comment: fix'd : https://www.google.ro/search?q=v201005080400+inurl%3Aeclipse.org&oq=v201005080400+inurl%3Aeclipse.org&aqs=chrome..69i57.4029j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=v201005080400+inurl:http:%2F%2Fdownload.eclipse.org%2Fwebtools%2Fdownloads%2Fdrops%2F

Comment: instead of manually adding each repo that's needed, i'm gonna add all the repos in the download.eclipse / webtools / downloads link. Thanks a bunch, @Jonah Graham !

Comment: hmm, added [this repo](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.1.0/R-3.1.0-20111121211311/repository/), but it still fails.

Comment: Have you tried the Simulatenous Release repo for Eclipse Indigo (3.7). That includes everything that was part of that release in one place: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue and forced to use eclipse 3.7. This repo url is not available anymore, any workarounds?

Comment: @alphaGeek the URLs broke - I updated the answer with new URLs.